# PK generated with EF Core is different on local SQL Server compared to Azure SQL (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS)

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database, ef-core-2.2

I'm using EF Core 2.2.6 and the schema generated on my local SQL Server 2017 (v14.0) is different from the schema generated on Azure (SQL Server v12.0)

My entity looks like this:

```
public class MyEntity 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My `DbContext` is:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) { 
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyTable").HasKey(m => m.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(m => m.Name).IsRequired();
}
```

But the problem is that in the Azure SQL database, the `ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS` is missing. Why is the generated schema different? Is there a way to force EF to add the `ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON` (and `ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON`)?

```
CREATE TABLE MyEntity 
(
    [Id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyEntity] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is how it looks in Azure:

```
CREATE TABLE MyEntity 
(
   [Id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
   [Name] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
   [Description] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_MyEntity] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                   WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Most likely these settings are simply not supported by Azure DB. There should be no functional difference, as `ON` is the default for both of these settings (and there is rarely a reason to deviate from this). You should not be expecting generated schemas to be character-for-character identical on every edition of SQL Server; that assumption breaks way too easily.

Comment: The reason I asked is because on the Azure db I'm having performance problems that by manually dropping and recreating the schema with the flags are solved

Comment: While it's not *impossible* that changing these flags is the solution, it is at least very *unlikely*. Recreating tables has other effects, like eliminating fragmentation. You could verify if there's really a difference in default flag behavior by checking the settings in `sys.indexes`. I expect no difference in `allow_row_locks`/`allow_page_locks` with these flags left out or explicitly specified as `ON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,  if you don't set the `ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF` or `ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF`, the table schema will be the same.

No matter in SQL Server or Azure SQL database, both the default value of `ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS` and `ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS` are **ON**:

Reference: [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :
[image]

You said you have the performance problems on Azure SQL database, I agree with  Jeroen Mostert that it's not impossible that changing these flags is the solution.

Maybe this document [Monitoring and performance tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitor-tune-overview) can give you more guides to solve the Azure SQL database performance problem.

Hope this helps.